# Hide NSTextView while some process is running

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsthread, nstextview, nsprogressindicator

My code is something like this:

```
- (void)buttonClick
{
  [self.progressIndicator startAnimation:self];
  [self.textView setHidden:YES];  

  // some process

  [self.progressIndicator stopAnimation:self];
  [self.textView setHidden:NO];
}
```

The problem is that `textView` is not hiding. And `progressIndicator` works properly, maybe because it's running in other thread. But when I tried to hide `textView` in some other thread or to perform in background it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

`NSTextView` is Embed in `NSScrollView` you also need to hidden `NSScrollView`

```
 - (void)buttonClick
{
  [self.progressIndicator startAnimation:self];
  [self.textView setHidden:YES]; 
  [scrollview setHidden:YES]; 

  // some process

  [self.progressIndicator stopAnimation:self];
  [self.textView setHidden:NO];
  [scrollview setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: Well, i'm actually using `NSTextField`, not `NSTextView`. But i think there is some problem with threads and UI freezing, because in other cases `setHidden:` works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can delay and then call by selectors, that would synchronize your threads (However this may not be the best way to do, you can use OperationQueue and GCD also). But this serves your purpose :

I have used NSTextField and NSTextView, as in your question and comment contains both.

```
-(void)someProcess:(id)sender{
    for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<9000; j++) {
            ;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"someProcess ends");
}

-(void)startProgressIndicator{
    [self.progressIndicator startAnimation:self];
}
-(void)stopProgressIndicator{
    [self.progressIndicator stopAnimation:self];
}
-(void)hideScroll{
    [self.textField setHidden:YES];
    [self.scrollView setHidden:YES];
}
-(void)showScroll{
    [self.textField setHidden:NO];
    [self.scrollView setHidden:NO];
}


- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    //hide scrollview
    NSLog(@"hide sv");
    [self hideScroll];

    //start prog indi
    NSLog(@"run");
    [self performSelector:@selector(startProgressIndicator) withObject:self afterDelay:1];

    //some process
    [self someProcess:nil];


    //stop prog indi
    NSLog(@"stop");
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopProgressIndicator) withObject:self afterDelay:1];


    //show scrollview
    NSLog(@"show sv\n\n\n\n");
    [self performSelector:@selector(showScroll) withObject:self afterDelay:1];

}
```